# How to find the minimum integer that is greater than 0 in an unsorted list of positive and negative integers?

Tags: python, minimum

I have an unsorted list of  integers `dist` containing positive and negative integers, and I would like to return the `index` of the `minimum number` that is `>0`. Here is my code:

```
dist = [-4,1,-2,4,5]

curr = dist.index(min(i) for i in dist if i>0)

print(curr)
```

I run into a `"ValueError(): generator is not in list"`, and I do understand the issue, the issue is that the output of the list comprehension is a generator, but how can I wrap it around something to make it valid? Usually I throw a `list()` around it, but this clearly will not work in the above case.

P.S. I know there are other ways to do it like using sort(), but in the actual problem I am solving, `dist` contains thusands of numbers, and I would like to avoid sorting the list. If there are other easier ways to do it, please do let me know!

Comment: Almost. Use `curr = dist.index(min(i for i in dist if i > 0))`.

Comment: Thank you! Do I need to close the question? Since I have a satisfactory answer?